# resultset of particular query

Tags: mysql

I have this query. When I execute I got Query statement but I want result set of this query.

My query is:

```
SELECT CONCAT('select * from ', table_name, ' union all ') AS CUSTOMQUERY
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_name LIKE '%custom%'
```

I get this result

```
select * from custom_70006 union all  
select * from custom_704306 union all  
select * from custom_700436 union all  
select * from custom_7000643 union all  
select * from custom_7000634 union all  
select * from custom_700046 union all  
select * from custom_700063 union all  
select * from custom_700062 union all
```

But I want result set of this particular column with corresponding data and last `union all` should remove.

Please help me with relevant query.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

SELECT @query1 := GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name) SEPARATOR
                         ' UNION ALL ') AS CUSTOMQUERY
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
       AND table_name LIKE '%custom%';


PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/954b5/2)

or modify your query as:

```
SELECT @query1 := CONCAT('select * from ', table_name, ' union all ') AS
       CUSTOMQUERY
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_name LIKE '%custom%'
```

to remove last `'union all'` string from your query:

```
SET @query1 = TRIM(TRAILING 'union all' FROM TRIM(@query1));
```

PS: Default value of [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) is only 1024. So you need to set it to higher value otherwise the output of your query will get stripped and you may get syntax error.

Comment: many thanx for the reply Omesh. actually as i wrote the last word of my query is  UNIONALLselect * from custom_70006 union all  
select * from custom_704306 union all  
select * from custom_700436 union all  
select * from custom_7000643 union all  
select * from custom_7000634 union all  
select * from custom_700046 union all  
select * from custom_700063 union all  
select * from custom_700062 union all so i have to remeove unionall first

Comment: you're welcome! you can store your query in variable `@query1` and the using `TRIM` function you can remove last `'union all'` string as: `TRIM(TRAILING 'union all' FROM TRIM(@query1))`

Comment: Omesh actually MYSQL is new for me . i do this in sql without any error. because i dont know how to decalare variables in mysql and execute them i faced lots of error. i think your 1st query need not any trim operation but when i execute this i get NULL as result.. Please help me with query if possible....

Comment: Yes first query is better approach and it don't require `TRIM` function. You might be gettting NULL result because of this condition `WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()` in WHERE clause, make sure that you are executing query from same database.

Comment: no,still i'm getting warning of multiple result.. i need to execute all tables values in one query . actually i need this in SSRS report and i'm trying to put this query in procedure and execute simplly a procedure in my ssrs dataset . but myqury not giving answer to me then procedure is second step for me. :(

Comment: You need to set this variables before your query. `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;` You are using `MySQL or SQL SERVER`? These queries will work for MYSQL only. Don't forget to answer the best answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: HI Omesh actually i need to use this in MYSQL i completely fine with sql server but mysql creates problem.
in sql i create this dynamic query ad put in procedure . that works fine i,e,when i execute that procedure i got data based on union all of all these tables. same i need in MYSQL,i used SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;
SELECT @query1 := GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.', table_name)
                               SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') AS CUSTOMQUERY
FROM Information_Schema.tables
WHERE  table_name LIKE '%custom%';
PREPARE stmt FROM @query1;
EXECUTE stmt;

Comment: statement executed SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_40001 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_40002 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70003 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70012 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70013 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70014 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70015 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70022 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70023 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_70032 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_

Comment: where last last tablename not covered in query.           even when use use 4000 series tables quey will be                                                                SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_40001 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_40002   so it should executed but still i get no resultset.  that means we have problem in execute statement..
i want to mark your comment as answer but i have no result...:(.. i think we are near by answer . my comment is too long ,so that i had to use 3 comments.

Comment: I can't get the exact problem you are facing with this first query. Do you get `SYNTAX ERROR` or `NO DATA` in output? If you are getting syntax error then you need to debug generated query by using `SELECT @query;` if you get no data then wither you  have no data in tables or missing some tables in query.

Comment: thanx for the reply Omesh. SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;
SELECT @query1 := GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.', table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') AS CUSTOMQUERY
FROM Information_Schema.tables
WHERE  table_name LIKE '%custom_400%';
query return this as result set    SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_40001 UNION ALL SELECT lead_id FROM asterisk.custom_40002  when i execute this in new window this query give result me . my problem is this should execute in dynamic query. my table is not empty.

Comment: r u using PHP? which version of MySQL? and u r executing query from `PHPmyadmin` or `linux konsole`? try executing first complete query manually upto `DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;` and see what you get.

Comment: i'm using MSQLQueryBrowser and i have PHP Admin.. but i always use MYSQLQUERYBROWSER. i got no resultset as output

Comment: Make sure that you have same column names and same number of columns in your union query. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

Comment: i'm trying to execute only one column instead of all .. i want to share printscreen please let me know where i can share printscreen .

Comment: You can edit your question here and add image in it. See this working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/954b5/2 & AND this is not working as in your case because of different number of columns in table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a605/1

Comment: how cani can in this because i see only loading window

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16401/discussion-between-omesh-and-neha-prajapati)